# paper-ripple prevents click on container element and doesn't fit

Tags: javascript, polymer

Here is the partial code to which i'm troubled.

```
<core-toolbar id="main-toolbar" horizontal layout>
    <core-icon-button icon="menu" class="bottom" core-drawer-toggle>
        <paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch" fit></paper-ripple>
    </core-icon-button>
    <div id="titulo" class="bottom" flex></div>
    <paper-fab id="viva-close-button" icon="close" class="bottom" mini></paper-fab>
</core-toolbar>
```

The expected behaviour is the ripple spreading till the end of the core-icon-button and only this element, plus, well, it should toggle the menu drawer. It **does** work without the ripple but with it innit just crash and burns.

The ripple goes all toolbar long and also seems to prevent the menu icon to receive the click event and doesn't trigger any action.
It all happens with menu items too but they are a tad more complex (in my case at least because i extended it's functionality) so i decided to give the drawer button a try.

**EDIT**
code working:

```
    <paper-icon-button role="button" icon="menu" relative core-drawer-toggle>
      <paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch circle" fit></paper-ripple>
    </paper-icon-button>
```

absolutely no need for fiddling. peper-icon-button works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fit` layout attribute you're using is equivalent to setting `position: absolute` with `top/right/bottom/left: 0`. As [explained in the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#general-purpose-attributes), this sizes the element so that it fills the first parent element with `position: relative` set. Since you'd like it to fill your `<core-icon-button>`, you can just set `position: relative` on that, as shown below (using the `relative` attribute, which is another shortcut that Polymer defines):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
    
    <template is="auto-binding">
      Positioned:
      <core-icon-button relative icon="menu" on-tap="{{alertTap}}">
        <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
      </core-icon-button>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      document.querySelector('template').alertTap = function(e) {
        console.log('Tapped!', e);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example also shows handling the `tap` event via a handler on the `<core-icon-button>`.

But... why not just use [`<paper-icon-button>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-icon-button) instead? It sounds like you're replicating a lot of that functionality, and I'm not sure what the benefit is.

Comment: or just use the `relative` attribute

Comment: thank you. it worked even better than in the snippet. thank you. i've read the docs plenty of times, but as you probably know they are always changing. ps.: you 2 could upvote the answer, it's quite informative and useful. i did.

Comment: not sure why it stopped working. i had to move the core-drawer-toggle to the paper-ripple itself :/

Comment: sorry @JeffPosnick, didn't notice your suggestion on peper-icon-button. it works perfectly, i came here to suggest that and realised you already did. thank you. again.